# ASP.NET MVC - Telerik MVC TreeView binding to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, treeview, telerik-mvc

my application is an asp.net MVC; I am using Telerik MVC Tree view to display nodes from a model, it works well, except when a value of one node is null.

here is my TreeView:

```
<% IEnumerable<MyTreeNode> tree = ViewBag.TreeData.Nodes; %>
<%= Html.Telerik().TreeView().Name("TreeView").BindTo(tree, mappings =>
         {
    mappings.For<MyTreeNode>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, myTreeNode) => {
                                    item.Text = myTreeNode.Text; })
                                    .Children(myTreeNode => myTreeNode.Nodes));
                                   })
  .ClientEvents(events => events.OnSelect("onSelect")) %>
```

I get the following error (pointing to myTreeNode.Text) "value" cannot be null or empty.

I tried:

```
  if (!IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text))
     {
      item.Text = myTreeNode.Text;
     }
```

I get this error: The name 'IsNullOrEmpty' does not exist in the current context.

Any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsNullOrEmpty() is a static method call on a string class.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text))
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, your solution worked well, no erros. However, I can see the TreeView, but no text.  Is there a way to just eliminate the node which has a null or empty value?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the Telerik Treeview, however the general rule of thumb in binding usually is manipulate the source data not the control that binds to the data. i.e. if you don't want to display an empty item remove it from the source list.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will check the model.

Comment: Just in case someone else has same problem, here is how it worked:   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myTreeNode.Text))
   item.Text = myTreeNode.Text;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
item.Text = (myTreeNode.Text != null) ? myTreeNode.Text : ""
```

or

```
item.Text = (myTreeNode != null) ? myTreeNode.Text : ""
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I still get ("value" cannot be null or empty.) error.